# Can Vital Strike be used with the Mind Knight Path maneuver?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Vital Strike:

> When you use the attack action, you can make one attack at your highest base attack bonus that deals additional damage. Roll the weapon’s damage dice for the attack twice and add the results together before adding bonuses from Strength, weapon abilities (such as flaming), precision-based damage, and other damage bonuses. These extra weapon damage dice are not multiplied on a critical hit, but are added to the total.

The Psychic Warrior [Mind Knight Path](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/psychic-warrior#TOC-Mind-Knight-Path) maneuver:

> Beginning at 3rd level, you can expend your psionic focus as a standard action to make a melee attack against two creatures adjacent to you. For every five psychic warrior levels you gain thereafter, you can make one additional attack against another enemy adjacent to you.

Both of them are standard actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No.

The effect of Vital Strike explicitly requires the use of the action [attack action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Attack), which is a standard action. From the [official FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9pyy):

> **Vital Strike: Can I use this with Spring Attack, or on a charge?**
>
> No. Vital Strike can only be used as part of an attack action, which is a specific kind of standard action. Spring Attack is a special kind of full-round action that includes the ability to make one melee attack, not one attack action. Charging uses similar language and can also not be used in combination with Vital Strike.

Like Spring Attack or Charge, the maneuver from the Mind Knight Path is its own action, which is not the attack action, hence Vital Strike's effect does not apply here.